# Add action hook into wp_localize_script

Tags: hooks, actions, wp-localize-script

Is it possible to add an action hook via `wp_localize_script`, so I can position where I want the hook to run in HTML markup that is made in the JavaScript?

So something like:

```
$data = array (
    'ng_slicknav' => array(
        'ng_slicksearch'           => home_url( '/' ),
        'ng_slicknav_closedsymbol' => esc_html( $options['ng_slicknav_closedsymbol'] ),
        'ng_slicknav_hook'         => do_action( 'myplugin_after_hook' ),
    ),
);
// Add filter
$data = apply_filters( 'ng_slicknav_slickNavVars', $data );

// Pass PHP variables to jQuery script
wp_localize_script( 'slicknav-init', 'slickNavVars', $data );

wp_enqueue_script( 'slicknav-init' );
```

The variable I am trying to add is `ng_slicknav_hook`, but anything I hook to it falls just outside of the HTML markup in JavaScript; it doesn't honor the position I put it in.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Is it possible to add an action hook via wp_localise_script
`'ng_slicknav_hook'         => do_action( 'myplugin_after_hook'),`

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working as expected. The problem is that your hook is rendering content to the page and you would like to pass that output to the javascript variable included in the JS output. You need to capture the hook output into a variable then add to `$data`.

```
// buffer output
ob_start();

   // run hook
   do_action('myplugin_after_hook');

// get the output buffer into a variable
$ng_slicknav_hook = ob_get_clean();

// add to data
$data = array(

    'ng_slicknav' => array(
        'ng_slicksearch'           => home_url('/'),
        'ng_slicknav_closedsymbol' => esc_html($options[ 'ng_slicknav_closedsymbol' ]),
        'ng_slicknav_hook'         => $ng_slicknav_hook,
    ),

);
```

It will most likely need to be escaped but I'll leave that to whatever content you're creating.

Comment: This almost works but what happens is that when reference it in my js file with 
`ng_slicknav.ng_slicknav_hook`
it outputs `null` to the page and even I do not reference the hook in my js it is still output to the page and anything hooked to it - but not where I want it positioned.

Comment: Is that a question or statement?

Comment: it is what happens

Comment: All the variables are attached to 'slickNavVars', what does that variable output? Localize script will just output before your JS so your JS has access to them.

Comment: Yes sorry should have been more explicit above when I use 
`slickNavVars.ng_slicknav.ng_slicknav_hook` in my js it outputs `null` - but the hook also just outputs regardless if used in js or not